# Search function stops working after converting to CDF

Tags: cdf-format

My problem is, that when a make a notebook and convert it to CDF using the 'CDF-Export', the  search field, which appears on CDF player, does not work. When trying to search for a word, the computer simply makes a sound indicating that the word was not found.
But when I use 'CDF-preview' before converting, the search field works just fine.

I have tried it with very simple notebooks and the problem is still there.

Am I the only one with this problem? Does anyone have an idea for a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution: Don't use the export wizard. Use 'Save as' and choose .cdf in stead. The conversion is a lot faster and the search function works on the resulting cdf-file.
I have tried this on two different computers and the result is the same:

With the wizard the search field does not work.
With 'save as' the search field works.